# Imputing outliers in r with sd+mean

Tags: r, function, for-loop, outliers

I wanted to find outliers 3sd away from the mean. I could do that with the following function. I want to add to the function a replace function. I want to replace the outliers with **mean+3sd+(participants value-mean)/mean)**. In this case should I use for loop? An example for loop I am trying to write is given below. how can the function and for loop be merged? or is there any other way to iterate over every row of the data (participants value) when replacing the outliers?
In the end, I want to have a new column as a result of the function. if all these can be achieved with dplyr mutate or aother functions I am open to any solution.

```
findingoutlier<- function (data, cutoff=3, na.rm=TRUE){
  sd <- sd(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  mean <- mean(data, na.rm=TRUE
  outliers <- (data[data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd])
  return (outliers)
  }

for (i in data) {
     x<- mean+3sd+(i-mean)/mean
     replace(data, outliers, x)
   }

# example data 
bmi <- c(32.8999, 31.7826, 28.5573, 20.6350, 21.6311, NA, 29.6174, 52.7027, 58.5968, 30.1867, 28.7927, 26.4697, 42.0294, 27.1309, 56.3672, 62.6474, 34.1692, 31.5120, 29.8553, 34.4443, 25.4049, 25.7287, 71.3209, 23.5615, 19.9359,21.7438, 51.9286, 22.1875, NA, 24.4389, 28.1571, 23.7093, 47.5551, 27.7767, 30.3237, NA, 20.7838, 34.1878, 25.1559, 25.8645, 24.9673, 27.5374, 28.5467, 25.0402, 22.1056, 28.0026, 26.7901, 21.5110,NA, 50.7599, NA, 32.6979, 26.5295, 25.5246, 23.9657, 20.1323, 28.0452)
eid <- c(1:57)
df <- cbind(eid, bmi)
df
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).  Do you want to replace outliers for each row separately?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah thank you. I will read the info. I want to replace outliers with the result of following equation: mean of the data+ 3*sd + (particpant's value (row's value) - mean of the data) / mean of the data. To achieve that I need a function that says minus mean of the data from each row and replace the original value with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that you can use index subsets not only as a right hand side value (something to be read from), but also as a left hand side value (something to be written to), as follows:

```
m <- mean(data, na.rm=TRUE)
s <- sd(data, na.rm=TRUE)
# get the *indices* of the outliers
indices <- (abs(m - data) > 3*s) | is.na(data)
# compute the replacement for *every* value
replacement <- (data + m) / m + 3*s
# replace *only* the outliers
data[indices] <- replacement[indices]
```

Comment: Thank you very much but when I run it I get the following error:   _Error in data[indices] <- replacement[indices] : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments_  How do I say that NAs must be kept

Comment: I have editied my answer to include a test for NA (is.na). As the computation or replacement yields NA for NA input, this will keep NAs. As you are anew contributor, here is a hint: if an answer actually answers the question, you should accept the answer, such that it is removed form the list of open questions.

Comment: I have run the follwoing code `test_1<- function(data) {
  m <- mean(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  s <- sd(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  indices <- (abs(m - data) > 3*s) | is.na(data)
  replacement <- (data + m) / m + m + 3*s
  data[indices] <- replacement [indices]
}` But I am getting an error saying the replacement data must be compatible with the existing data. _x Existing data has 502506 rows.
x Assigned data has 9097 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled._

Comment: Just tested the function with your test data from the question with `data <- test_1(df[,2])`, and I do not get an error. Moreover, `data != df[,2]` reports that actually one value was replaced.